# jQuery children of cloned element not responding to events

Tags: events, jquery

**Summary**

I am using jQuery to clone a div ("boxCollection") containing groups ("groupBox") each of which contains a set of inputs.  The inputs have change events tied to them at `$(document).ready`, but the inputs inside the cloned divs do not respond to the event triggers.  I can not get this to work in IE7, IE8, or FF3.

Here is my sample code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="boxCollection"><div class="groupBox" id="group_1"><input type="text"></input></div></div>
```

**jQuery events:**

```
$(".groupBox[id*='group']").change(function(){
    index = $(this).attr("id").substring(6);
    if($("input[name='collection_"+index+"']").val() == "")
    {
        $("input[name='collection_"+index+"']").val("Untitled Collection "+index);
    }
});
```

**jQuery clone statement:**

```
$(".boxCollection:last").clone(true).insertAfter($(".boxCollection:last"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) to automatically put event handlers on dynamically created elements:

```
$(".groupBox[id*='group']").live("change", function() {
  ...
});
```

You appear to be putting a `change()` event handler on a `<div>` however (based on your sample HTML). Also, I would recommend not using an attribute selector for this. You've given it a class so instead do:

```
$("div.groupBox ...")...
```

Lastly, you are trying to give each text input a unique name. You don't say what your serverside technology is but many (most?) will handle this better than that. In PHP for example you can do:

And `$_POST` will contain an element "box" with an array of three values.

Comment: `live` is deprecated.

Comment: The replacement for `live` is `on`.  There are a few differences so you may need to do a bit of research if a straight replace does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but I'm going to give it a shot and say that you need to assign live events

```
$(".groupBox[id*='group']").live('change', function() { });
```

You'll probably have a problem with `change` and `live` in IE6/7, so I advise you to use the [livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) plugin to resolve that issue.

Comment: `live` is deprecated.